# Combinatorics Question Relating to "At least"

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, computer-science

Your help is greatly appreciated, rather simple question but not quite sure how to go about it.

Determine how many different possible combinations of computer science classes numbered 300 or above would satisfy the computer science major under the following assumptions (which, for the sake of this problem, are simpler than the actual requirements):

**You must take both 301 and 302.
You must take exactly two of 311, 312, 313, and 314.
You must take exactly three of eight classes numbered over 320.**

A) Express your answer as an equation that gives insight into the answer, and then solve the equation.

B) Revise your answer under the assumption that you must take at least two of 311, 312, 313, and 314, and that the total number of courses taken numbered over 310 is exactly five.

Ok so I was able to figure out the first part of the question. You ignore the first assumption because you have to do them both anyways. Then you just take 4 choose 2 and multiply that by 8 choose 3 using the product rule (336)

What I do not understand is the second part of the question, where it changes to "at least two" How does this change the equation?

Comment: "You must take exactly three of eight classes numbered over 320." Did you mean over 302 ? Also, are you familiar with the principle of inclusion-exclusion ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @trueblueanil No the wording is correct, it is supposed to be three of eight classes over 320. In this scenario, we are just assuming that there is eight classes numbered over 320. And no I am not, I believe this question is centered around Combinatorics and product rule

Answer (score 1):

If you need to take "at least two" out of the four courses, then you need to take either two, three or all four of them. You could calculate the number of combinations this creates either by:

- Counting the possibilities for 2, 3 and 4 separately, and adding them together; or
- Counting the number of ways to take *any number* of the classes, and subtracting the number of ways to take 0 or 1 of them.

Depending on how familiar you are with certain concepts, the second could be quicker but more difficult.

Comment: Based on what you said, would I be correct in my understanding to make the equation: (12 choose 5) - (4 choose 2)? @ConMan

Comment: @WizardlyFellow569  That is not correct.  Try the first method.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I am unsure of what the first method is trying to imply in regards to formulating an equation to find the amount of combinations given the revised assumption

Comment: @WizardlyFellow569 If two select exactly two of 311, 312, 313, 314, you must select select $5 - 2 = 3$ classes numbered over 320; if you select exactly three of 311, 312, 313, 314, you must select $5 - 3 = 2$ classes numbered over 320; if you select all four of the classes 311, 312, 313, 314, you must select $5 - 4 = 1$ class numbered over 320.  Those three cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, so you can add the results to obtain the answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for demonstrating, I am assuming in this response that you are getting the five from the second part of the revision being "total courses taken over 310 is exactly five". To answer part B of the question then would it just be 12 choose 5 * 6 then? I am unsure as to how to structure the equation formula for part B with this context in mind.

Comment: @WizardlyFellow569  You did part (a) correctly.  That addresses the case when you take exactly two of the courses 311, 312, 313, 314 and three of the courses numbered higher than 320.  You still have the other two cases I mentioned, which are done analogously.  You then add the results.